# Использовать ли оператор return , если функция ничего не возвращает?

Tags: c#, функции, типы-данных

Нужно ли использовать оператор return в функции, тип возвращаемого значения которой указан как void, или же его просто опускать? В чем разница таких подходов?

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    SomeInstructions;
    return;
}
```

Comment: В вопросах по синтаксису, пожалуйста, уточняйте о каком языке идет речь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не нужно. Компилятор сам сообразит. Разницы в наличии и отсутствии явного `return` для функции без возвращаемого значения нет, кроме появления лишней строчки.